# why do the leaves of my papaya tree twist and dry

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases, papaya

I have papaya and mango saplings. But there are such problems on their leaves. Could you please help me ??I wanted to send a photo but I could not upload it.

Comment: There are tens or maybe a hundred reasons for plants to show problems. It would be helpful if you could give details about them: appearance, colour, shape, other info maybe. Or maybe try to upload again. What happens after you try to upload? Is there an error message, or the pic simply doesn't show up after clicking the button?

Comment: Show us a picture please! see [help] on how to do it.